Python Selenium ChromeDriverManager Install Path Error THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver
I've been running into a problem in Python's Selenium ChromeDriverManager on a Mac (ARM64/M3 Chip).
When I run the below Python code, I get the following error:
[Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Users/adam.westbrook/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/129.0.6668.89/chromedriver-mac-arm64/THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver'
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()))

For some reason, the ChromeDriverManager is trying to use THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver as the driver rather than the file chromedriver.
When I look at the folder, the filetype of the file chromedriver shows it's a Document rather than a Unix Executable File.
But when I manually unzip the zip file that was automatically downloaded, chromedriver then correctly shows it's a Unix Executable File.
How can I fix this?

This solution that ChatGPT provided fixed the issue for me.
It essentially needs to remap the path from THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver to just chromedriver. Then set it so that it's an executable file.
This solution works for me!
import os
import stat
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Use webdriver_manager to install ChromeDriver
driver_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
driver_path = driver_path.replace('THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver', 'chromedriver')
file_stat = os.stat(driver_path)

# Ensure the downloaded chromedriver has executable permissions
# Check if it’s a valid file and set the executable bit
# i.e. explicitly sets the file’s permissions to be readable, writable, and executable by the user (you). This ensures that macOS recognizes it as an executable binary.
if os.path.exists(driver_path) and stat.S_ISREG(file_stat.st_mode):
    os.chmod(driver_path, stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR)

# Use the installed ChromeDriver for Selenium
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(executable_path=driver_path))


Check the webdriver-manager version. If you are still using 4.0.0 version, upgrade it to latest version.
pip install --upgrade webdriver-manager

This fixed the issue for me.
